# How can different Google sites share cookies

Tags: security, cookies, web

(I don't know if this is the right SE site for my question; if not, please direct me to the right site. Thanks!)

I'm learning about the same-origin policy and begin wondering how different Google sites (with different origins) can share the knowledge that a certain user is logged in. For example, logging in on https://www.google.com will also log me in for https://www.youtube.com. How can the latter know?